# Why do apps downloaded from playstore and Apkpure have same fingerprint?

Tags: android, apk, signing, jks, der

What I want is:
I want to generate Apk which on installing will give me an update of my app from Playstore.

What I observed:
I tried downloading WhatsApp from ApkPure kind of websites, installed that and updated same from Playstore, which is only possible when both have same fingerprint. But when we opt-in for app-signing by google, how do we sign with the same which google used? And there are millions of apps when installed from apk and can be updated from playstore when update is available there.

If we can sign Apk somehow from the deployment certificate which google gives us from play console, then also please let me know.

Comment: If you want to use Google Play app signing but also want to be able to sign the app yourself, then you should pick the option to upload an existing key instead of letting Google Play generate a new one when you activate app signing. AFAIK there is no way to download the key afterwards.

Comment: As far as _"And there are millions of apps when installed from apk and can be updated from playstore when update is available there"_ is concerned: then presumably the developers of those apps sign their apps themselves, or at least with a key they have generated themselves.

Comment: Thanks @Michael. I think that's the right answer to my question. I will try to upload existing key for new app.

Comment: side question, how do you all track installs from apkpure? I am using Firebase and I cannot really see apkpure numbers in Firebase.. but in Firebase, I have source "empty" numbers and I guess they are from websites like apkpure...

Comment: @AungMyintThein, currently we are not tracking installs from apkpure.. but we use a separate variant/flavour for apkpure. we use separate header in all the api requests, so on server side have track of source of all the registered users.

But definitely you can do something more/better than this